# Shiny - hide actionButton created dynamically when renderUI value is null

Tags: r, shiny

I have the app below (simplified example). Basically I would like that, when I turn on the app, if the reactive value is equal to `""` than I do not want that the `activeButton` appears on the UI. At the moment is appearing but without label. How can I do in this case? Thank you for your help!

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui=
    shinyUI(fluidPage(

        mainPanel(
            textInput("text", label = ""),
            uiOutput("wordOneButton")
        )
    ))
,

server=shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {
    reval <- reactive(sample(c("a", "b", ""), 1))

    # Fill the buttons with the random letter
    output$wordOneButton <- renderUI({
        actionButton("action", label = reval()[1])
        })


    # Include predicted word in the text after click event on button
    observeEvent(input$action, {
        name <- paste0(input$text, reval()[1], sep = " ")
        updateTextInput(session = session, "text", value = name)
    })

})
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `shinyjs::toggle()`:

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(ui=
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
        shinyjs::useShinyjs(), #NEW
        mainPanel(
            textInput("text", label = ""),
            uiOutput("wordOneButton")
        )
    ))
,

server=shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {
    reval <- reactive(sample(c("a", "b", ""), 1))

    # Fill the buttons with the random letter
    output$wordOneButton <- renderUI({
        actionButton("action", label = reval()[1])
        })

    observe(shinyjs::toggle("wordOneButton", condition = reval() != "")) #NEW

    # Include predicted word in the text after click event on button
    observeEvent(input$action, {
        name <- paste0(input$text, reval()[1], sep = " ")
        updateTextInput(session = session, "text", value = name)
    })

})
))
```

Comment: This works, but do you think there is a way to do it with the 'shinyjs' package?

Comment: because currently I am having problems deploying the app in the shinyapps.io server: Attaching package: ‘shinyjs’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    runExample

The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:

    removeClass, show (and I already specified the package with shinyjs::toggle())

Comment: I updated my answer above to remove the library call for `shinyjs` and explicitly calling the package in the two lines where I'm using its functions.

Comment: Hi! This works, I forgot to remove the library call! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible without calling an additional library. Two functions you are looking for are `validate()` and `need()`. Just add a couple of lines validating that the reactive `reval()` is different than the empty string `""`:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui=
              shinyUI(fluidPage(

                mainPanel(
                  textInput("text", label = ""),
                  uiOutput("wordOneButton")
                )
              ))
            ,

            server=shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {
              reval <- reactive(sample(c("a", "b", ""), 1))

              # Fill the buttons with the random letter
              output$wordOneButton <- renderUI({

                # Validate that reval() is distinct than ""
                shiny::validate(
                  shiny::need(reval() != "", message = "")
                )

                actionButton("action", label = reval()[1])
              })


              # Include predicted word in the text after click event on button
              observeEvent(input$action, {
                name <- paste0(input$text, reval()[1], sep = " ")
                updateTextInput(session = session, "text", value = name)
              })

            })
))
```

I'm using the `shiny::` calls to explicitly use these functions from the `shiny` library and avoid errors in case you use other libraries such as `jsonlite` that share functions with the same name. If you don't use this library, feel free to erase the `shiny::` calls.

Also, you can add a message in case `reval()` does equal the empty string `""`. Just change the `message` parameter inside the `need()` function.